# How to draw MVC diagram in Microsoft modeling tools?

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, visio

I want to draw a MVC diagram in Microsoft Modeling tools like visio or Visual studio and the diagram looks like this:
http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller-03.png

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy job:
First, open Visio and select 'Blank Drawing'.
Second, select 'More Shapes' on the left panel and then select 'Software and Database', next Web Diagram, finally Conceptual Web Site Shape. 
Last, select the left top one: a rectangle shape with a header to stand for the package, and select normal rectangle shape for sub package or sub module.

To use arrow, just go to 'More Shapes'/'FlowChart'/'Arrow Shapes'. The procedure is same as above.